# Reduce Membase quota per bucket to 5 MB

Tags: memcached, membase

In Heroku, I notice that they limit my free Memcached Bucket (actually Membase) to 5MB. However, I tried it on my own server and cannot set Bucket quota to less than 64MB (per node, and for Memcached bucket type). For Membase bucket type, it's even more: 100MB.
Hmm, my server have a humble amount of RAM. And I need to allocate a very small amount of Memcached. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is running a slightly modified version of our memcached software that lets them keep the bucket overhead very low.  Unfortunately the "productized" version has some limits imposed to prevent the software from getting itself into trouble.

Especially for Membase buckets, we need at least 100mb in order to safely run.

You may be able to reduce/eliminate these limits if you recompile the source, but that wouldn't be a supported configuration.

Perry

Comment: Isn't that Membase bases on Memcached? Why Memcached only requires 64MB while Membase requires 100MB? Are they allocated immediately or over a period of time?

Comment: There are extra data structures within Membase buckets in order to handle the various "magic" that we do in terms of persistence, replication, etc.

Comment: Most of that will be allocated immediately but RAM for any data you put in will be allocated at the time of entry.

Comment: Can you clarify on what's allocated immediately? By the way, if I install memcached instead of membase, would it not eatup that much ram from my system, given I don't use Memcached that much?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the  delay in getting back to this...

As with any piece of software, there are internal data structures that need RAM to run...that's what gets allocated immediately with Membase.

If you install memcached, it will use as much RAM as you configure it to use...no more, no less.